# calculate lat/long bounding box using Pyproj, Shapely, GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pyproj

I need to calculate the min/max latitude/longitude co-ordinates within a specified distance (in km) from a given latitude/longitude using Python.

From my googling, it seems like the best packages out there are GeoPandas, Shapely and Pyproj but I'm unable to find a nice simple example that solves this problem and I'm finding it difficult to wade through all the associated documentation.  I just need to solve this one particular problem so am trying to avoid spending a week reading through these very sophisticated packages.

I am able to install and import shapely and Pyproj but installing GeoPandas looks very daunting based on the number of packages that either need to be installed from new or upgraded.  So shapely/Pyproj solutions are much preferred.

If anybody can cobble together a simple example that I can cannibalize, I would be very grateful.

Catherine

Comment: Please show us where you’re starting from, what you’ve tried, etc. see the guide to [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Comment: Also have you tried using conda? Download miniconda, then `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge geopandas cartopy` then `conda activate myenv` and you’re set!